# Layouts file used in android either from default or from mdpi

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, screen

I have created a general layout in res/layout/ directory and another layout in res/layout-mdpi directory to overried for mdpi devices. Which layout shall be used for hdpi and xhdpi devices? And Why?

I expected the override should work for only mdpi but this isnt the case. What should be my config a layout file in hdpi and mdpi and no layout file in defaults? Or perhaps the mdpi layout file should placed in default and the default layout should be placed in hdpi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no layout file in general folder, android will select one in any layout folder(I have no idea what it will select).
For example, if main.xml in only layout-mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi shall use main.xml in mdpi folder.

I recommend you to read this article. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html